# Grouping Values to Key in Ansible

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, ansible, jinja2

Is there a way to group the values of **subnet4**, **ipv4-address**, **ipv4-address-first  -  ipv4-address-last** to a key, "**IP**"

**playbook.yml**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  
  - name: lookup file
    set_fact: 
       li: "{{ lookup('file', 'log.yml') | from_yaml }}"
  - name: run script
    command: 'python3 yaml_to_csv.py'
```

**log.yml**

```
- comments: FWP - Address Range
  ipv4-address-first: 10.1.2.3
  ipv4-address-last: 10.1.2.5
  ipv4-address: null
  subnet4: null
  subnet-mask: null
  type: address-range
  name: gTest101
- comments: FWP - Host
  ipv4-address-first: null
  ipv4-address-last: null
  ipv4-address: 10.1.2.6
  subnet4: null
  subnet-mask: null
  type: host
  name: gTest102
- comments: FWP - Network
  ipv4-address-first: null
  ipv4-address-last: null
  ipv4-address: null
  subnet4: 41.1.2.3
  subnet-mask: 255.255.255.255
  type: network
  name: gTest103
- comments: FWP - Host 4
  ipv4-address-first: null
  ipv4-address-last: null
  ipv4-address: 10.1.2.7
  subnet4: null
  subnet-mask: null
  type: host
  name: gTest104
```

This is the python code I call in Ansible to do the job

**yaml_to_csv.py**

```
import csv
import yaml

# creating header for the csv file
fields = {
    'name' : 'Name',
    'ipv4-address' : 'IP',
    'subnet4' : 'Subnet4',
    'subnet-mask' : 'Subnet-Mask',
    'ipv4-address-first' : 'IPv4-Address-First',
    'ipv4-address-last' : 'IPv4-Address-Last',
    'comments' : 'Comments',
    'type' : 'Type',
}

# open file and write header data to file
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fields.values())
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for filename in ['log.yml']:
        with open(filename) as f_input:
            for row_yaml in yaml.safe_load(f_input):
                row_csv = {fields[key] : value for key, value in row_yaml.items()}
                csv_output.writerow(row_csv)
```

**As I ran the playbook**

[image]

This the my csv file output

**output.csv**
[image]

**Below is the expected output that I want to achieve **

[image]

Is there something I might be missing, or there a better approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Did the [`| groupby` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#groupby) not do what you expected?

Comment: @mdaniel I have never heard of group by filter. How do apply that?

Comment: Does that mean the documentation link that I provided is broken for you? Either way, this is a programming site, so [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67820286/edit) to show your attempted code, and the error it is producing for you in order for anyone to help you

Comment: I am really struggling to see what problem you are facing, and that goes 100x now that you have written custom python (versus trying to do it in jinja2, which I can appreciate is sometimes hard to grok). Isn't it `row_csv["IP"] = f'{first} - {last}' if (first and last) else ipv4-address if ipv4-address else subnet4` type deal?